# set background of select tag same on parent div's background

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make language switcher like this:

[image]

I have added

```
select {
border: none;
background: url(../Photos/bg.png) no-repeat;
}
```

but after that it looks like:

[image]

how can i improve that?

**I dont know why but in jsfiddle everything is ok.** but in browser it's different

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9hu47w4v/)

Comment: u r checked fiddle o/p in mozila?

Comment: What do you mean by improve that? Change `color`, `padding`?

Comment: @MatthewT.Baker color. It's different in black geo. i mean background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works in Firefox, but doesn't work in IE (you should have specified this in the question, TBH).

Instead of trying to uniform the way each browser paint the box around the second background image, the Egg of Columbus is to set the background transparent:

```
select {
  background : transparent;
      border : none;
       color : white;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9hu47w4v/1/)